# cannot find -ll collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: gcc, cygwin, ld, yacc, lex

I got a similar error when I tried to compile my `lex.yy.c` file generated from `lex helloworld.l` using `gcc lex.yy.c -ll` in cygwin.

The helloworld.l contains

```
%%
[0-9]+ { printf("saw an integer:%s\n", yytext);}
[a-z]+ { printf("saw a lowercase character:%s\n", yytext);}
[A-Z]+ { printf("saw an uppercase character:%s\n", yytext);}
.|\n ;
%%
```

The output for `gcc lex.yy.c -ll` was

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me resolve this error and get this to work. Thank you!

Comment: Try changing `-ll` to `-lfl`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you @rici

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @rici

```
$ gcc lex.yy.c -lfl

$ ./a < helloworld.l
saw an integer:0
saw an integer:9
saw a lowercase character:printf
saw a lowercase character:saw
...
```

Why ? The program `lex`belongs to the `flex`package and
the import library is `libfl.a`

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/lex
flex-2.6.4-2

$ cygcheck -l flex | grep a$
/usr/lib/libfl.a
```

Comment: Thank you it worked @matzeri. I am unable to upvote your answer because I don't have reputation of 15 so sorry for that.

Comment: Accepting the answer is enough for you. Upvote is for other users that could appreciate the answer.